# How to setup multiple stores with multiple languages each?

Tags: multistore, language

I try to figure out the best way to setup multiple stores sharing the same catalog.

I don't have a problem to set up the store with 2 languages (de,en). Adding stores in one language is not a problem too, since they will use the "admin" values (e.g. german). But I want to (programmtically) add stores that will each have 2 language views:

- main store -> storeview de / storeview en
- extra store1 -> storeview de / storeview en
- extra store 2 -> storeview de / storeview en
- .....
- extra store 50 -> storeview de / storeview en

So far, it looks like I have to import the second language in each store view?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the stores, if it is not the catalog and not the language?

Answer (score 2):

If your second store views are purely for language, and *nothing else*. You would almost definitely fair better in terms of scalability and performance if you extended the core functionality for translation and assigned different CSV's based on either URL or IP.

That way, you can avoid having dozens of redundant stores - taking up resources that only exist for a simple language translation.

Comment: Yes, stores ("store views") are expensive.